# Kohana 3 ORM list columns

Tags: php

In Kohana 3 ORM, how can I list all the "column names" of a table and place them in an array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use database `list_columns()` method.

Example:

```
$columns = Database::instance()->list_columns('tablename');
```

In this case you'll get columns of `tablename` taken from `default` database connection.

Answer (score 2):

```
ORM::factory('table')->list_columns();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$result = $this->db->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM table');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder

Comment: doesn't address how to do it in kohana orm speak